# How to store values in onSaveInstanceState() and retrive?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Am trying to store value of a arraylist in `onSavedInstanceState()` and get the values in a array list in onCreate method but it raises an eeror like unable to pause activity

here is my code

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("Old", (Parcelable) profileDetails );
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and in my `onCreate()`

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) { 
    profileDetails= (ArrayList<ProfileDetails>)savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Old");
}
else {
    profileDetails = GetSearchResults();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant cascade arraylist to parcable this link help you for parcle arraylist [Android ArrayList<MyObject> pass as parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953121/android-arraylistmyobject-pass-as-parcelable)
this code may help you

```
public class ParcleListTopic implements Parcelable{
    private List<ParcleTopic> list;
    private ArrayList<HoldListTopic> listh=new ArrayList<HoldListTopic>();
    public ArrayList<HoldListTopic> GetListTopic()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            listh.add(list.get(i).GetHold());
        }
        return listh;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeTypedList(list);
    }
    public ParcleListTopic(Parcel in)
    {
        in.readTypedList(list,ParcleTopic.CREATOR);

    }
    public ParcleListTopic(List<ParcleTopic> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcleListTopic> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcleListTopic>(){
          public ParcleListTopic createFromParcel(Parcel s)
          {
              return new ParcleListTopic(s);
          }
          public ParcleListTopic[] newArray(int size) 
          {
                return new ParcleListTopic[size];
          }
    };
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}


public class ParcleTopic implements Parcelable
{
    HoldListTopic hold;
    public ParcleTopic(HoldListTopic hold)
    {
        this.hold=hold;
    }
    public HoldListTopic GetHold()
    {
        return hold;
    }
    public int describeContents() 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(hold.Title);
        dest.writeString(hold.Date);
        dest.writeInt(hold.NumberComment);
        dest.writeInt(hold.ID);
    }
    public ParcleTopic(Parcel in)
    {
        hold.Title=in.readString();
        hold.Date=in.readString();
        hold.NumberComment=in.readInt();
        hold.ID=in.readInt();
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcleTopic> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcleTopic>()
    {
          public ParcleTopic createFromParcel(Parcel s)
          {
              return new ParcleTopic(s);
          }
          public ParcleTopic[] newArray(int size) 
          {
                return new ParcleTopic[size];
          }
    }; }
```

Comment: i 'll try it and let u know!

Answer (score 6):

Bundle can store `Serializable` objects too.

Make sure than your `class ProfileDetails implements Serializable`.

After that you will be able to save/restore ArrayList in Bundle using:

```
savedInstanseState.putSerializable("Old", profileDetails);
...
profileDetails = (ArrayList<ProfileDetails>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Old");
```

Also you should guarantee that `class ProfileDetails` contains only fields of primitive types or Serializable (Strings, Arrays already implements this interface).

Answer (score 5):

to save value in save instance state

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

to restore value

```
@Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
    double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
    int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
  }
```

Comment: i need to refer the an arrayList values in my onCreate() method !

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity this is the error which am getting !

Comment: try to use savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("bookThumb", bookData);
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("bookBitmaps", bitmaps);
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("featureBook", bookIds);

Comment: am getting unable to marshal ! error when i do like u suggest !