# Passing data between activities from listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am trying to pass the data from this main activity to another activity

*I am successful in sending data between activities .... Like the data from Edit-text to next activity through `putExtra` and `GetExtra` methods and passing as intents*

- But i am facing challenge in this  particular task where it involves
  sending data from listview to an ordinary activity
- data is populated in the list view from JSON so when on click of a
  row how can i send the data from that row to a new activity

**Any Ideas,**

---

**ativity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7002/";
    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONObjParser jParser = new JSONObjParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");

                    yourData.add(new Item(NAME));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
            ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        //code specific to first list item    
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }else if(position == 1)
                    {
                        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AroyDesc.class);
                        //startActivity(myIntent);                  
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

**item.java**

```
public class Item{
    private String Name;

    public Item(String name){
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**Thanks,**

Comment: so you trying to pass the restaurent name that you clicked in listview

Comment: In onItemClick, you can get the clicked item using: Item item = yourData.get(position); Now you can pass this item using intent.putExtra, By the way, how does this Item object look like

Comment: I have updated how item object looks like in the question ... please have a look at it ..... i tried your solution im getting the error in the putextra line as `The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Item)`

Comment: Ok so you would do String item = yourData.get(position).getName(); Then you can add the string to intent using: intent.putExtra("restaurent", item);

Comment: Thanks, Hey on the final end of another activity how can i get the extra since im not using basket to send the data ..... i find the textview using `findviewbyid` then ?

Comment: On the other end if its textview you would to textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("restaurent")); I am gonna right this in answer, and please mark it correct if i solved your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so you would do

```
String item = yourData.get(position).getName();
```

Then you can add the `string` to `intent` using:

```
intent.putExtra("restaurent", item);
```

On the other end if its `textview` you would do

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("restaurent"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra("City Name", String.valueOf(lvCity.getSelectedItem()));
```

try this one to cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in `sharedPreferences` and can access it from other activity. Just an idea :)

Comment: But how to get the data(JSON) from the listview and store it in a string ... any ideas ?

Comment: if the data is static, like `session_key`, I think the `SharePreference` is way to go.

Comment: mJsonString = downloadFileFromInternet(urls[0]);
if(mJsonString == null /*|| mJsonString.isEmpty()*/)
return false;

      JSONObject jObject = null;
      try {
       jObject = new JSONObject(mJsonString);
          JSONArray jsonImageArray = jObject.getJSONArray("imageTarget");

Answer (score 0):

you can parcle data and send it to other activity with putxtera method.please see [How to store values in onSaveInstanceState() and retrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183432/how-to-store-values-in-onsaveinstancestate-and-retrive/17183535#17183535)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the index of the item in the listview the user has clicked you can get the item value from the adapter:

```
String value = (String)customAdapter.getItem(position);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
intent.putExtra("restaurant_name", value);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but im getting error `Cannot cast from item to string` .... any ideas on how to resolve this