# How to use userId from listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an issue related to ListView, in this listview each row have own auction_id ,I want to use that auction_id when we click on the row and use auction_id in another Activity as a JSON input , please help me

here is my code

```
private void getMyAuctionList(JSONObject response){
    //MyAuctionListBean listBean = new MyAuctionListBean();
    List<MyAuctionListBean> list = new ArrayList<MyAuctionListBean>();

    if(response != null){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("success");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                MyAuctionListBean listBean = new MyAuctionListBean();
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                listBean.setAuction_id(jsonObject1.getString("auction_id"));
                listBean.setEvent_name(jsonObject1.getString("event_name"));
                listBean.setContact_no(jsonObject1.getString("contact_no"));
                listBean.setAuction_date(jsonObject1.getString("auction_date"));
                listBean.setEnd_date(jsonObject1.getString("end_date"));
                listBean.setLocation(jsonObject1.getString("location"));
                listBean.setPeople_range(jsonObject1.getString("people_range"));
                listBean.setPrice_range(jsonObject1.getString("price_range"));
                listBean.setIs_active(jsonObject1.getString("is_active"));
                listBean.setTotal_bid_count(jsonObject1.getString("total_bid_count"));
                listBean.setTotal_quoted(jsonObject1.getString("total_quoted"));
                listBean.setTAproved(jsonObject1.getString("TAproved"));
                listBean.setAuction_description(jsonObject1.getString("auction_description"));
                list.add(listBean);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    hAdapter = new MyAuctionHistoryAdapter(getActivity(),list);
    hRecyclerView.setAdapter(hAdapter);
}
```

here is second Activity

```
private void getAuctionDetail(){

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(mSharedPreferences==null)
        return;
    String authorizationKey = mSharedPreferences.getString("authorization_key","");
    String userId = mSharedPreferences.getString("userId", "");
    //MyAuctionListBean listBean = new MyAuctionListBean();

    try {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.putOpt("authorization_key",authorizationKey);
        jsonObject.putOpt("in_user_id",userId);
        jsonObject.putOpt("device_token","1111");
        jsonObject.putOpt("mac_address","1111");
        jsonObject.putOpt("gps_latitude","1111");
        jsonObject.putOpt("gps_longitude","1111");
        jsonObject.putOpt("in_auction_id","");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.MYAUCTION_DETAIL_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            getMyAuctionDetails(response);
            Utility.showLogError(AuctionActivity.this, "GetAuctionDetailsResponse" + response.toString());
            pDialog.hide();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });
    Utility.showLogError(AuctionActivity.this, "Error in Detail"+"GetAuctionDetails URL = " + Constants.MYAUCTION_DETAIL_URL);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}

private void getMyAuctionDetails(JSONObject response) {
    MyAuctionDetailsBean myAuctionDetailsBean = new MyAuctionDetailsBean();
    if (response != null){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("success");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setAuction_id(jsonObject.getString("auction_id"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setContact_person(jsonObject.getString("contact_person"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setPrimary_contact_no(jsonObject.getString("primary_contact_no"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setAlternate_contact_no(jsonObject.getString("alternate_contact_no"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setAuction_title(jsonObject.getString("auction_title"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setClient_email(jsonObject.getString("client_email"));

                myAuctionDetailsBean.setStart_date(jsonObject.getString("start_date"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setEnd_date(jsonObject.getString("end_date"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setLocation(jsonObject.getString("location"));

                myAuctionDetailsBean.setPeople_range(jsonObject.getString("people_range"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setPrice_range(jsonObject.getString("price_range"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setFeatures_id(jsonObject.getString("features_id"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setCuisine_id(jsonObject.getString("cuisine_id"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setIs_active(jsonObject.getString("is_active"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setTheme_id(jsonObject.getString("theme_id"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setEvent_type_id(jsonObject.getString("event_type_id"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setTotal_bid_count(jsonObject.getString("total_bid_count"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setTotal_quoted(jsonObject.getString("total_quoted"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setTAproved(jsonObject.getString("TAproved"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setAuction_description(jsonObject.getString("auction_description"));
                myAuctionDetailsBean.setEvent_name(jsonObject.getString("event_name"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    partyType.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getEvent_name());
    location.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getLocation());
    date.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getStart_date());
    time.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getEnd_date());
    theme.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getTheme_id());
    noOfPeople.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getPeople_range());
    mobileNo.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getPrimary_contact_no());
    emailId.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getClient_email());
    cuisine.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getCuisine_id());
    requirment.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getAuction_description());
    budget.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getPrice_range());
    postUser.setText(myAuctionDetailsBean.getContact_person());
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
public class MyAuctionHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAuctionHistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<MyAuctionListBean> list;
private Context hContext;
private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public MyAuctionHistoryAdapter(Context hContext,List<MyAuctionListBean> list){
    this.hContext = hContext;
    this.list = list;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.auction_history_row,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.partyType.setText(list.get(position).getEvent_name());
    holder.partyLocation.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getAuction_date());
    holder.bidCount.setText(list.get(position).getTotal_bid_count());
    holder.priceRange.setText(list.get(position).getPrice_range());
    holder.auctionDetailRowLay.setId(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getAuction_id()));
    holder.rowAuction_Id.setText(list.get(position).getAuction_id());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView partyType,partyLocation,restroType,budget,requirments,date,priceRange,bidCount;
    private RelativeLayout auctionDetailRowLay;
    private ImageView restoIcon;
    TextView rowAuction_Id;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {

        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        partyType = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auctionPartyType);
        partyLocation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auctionLocation);
        restroType = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.restro_Name);
        budget = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auction_Budget);
        requirments = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auctionRequirments);
        date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auctionDate);
        bidCount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auction_Bids);
        priceRange = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.H_auction_RangeList);
        auctionDetailRowLay= (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.auctionDetailRow);
        rowAuction_Id = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_Auction_id);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(hContext, AuctionActivity.class);
        hContext.startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Where is `onItemClickListener` code?

Comment: lots of irrelevant code, but the important parts (click listener, how you open the other activity, where do you want to get the id in the other activity, ...) are missing

Comment: onItemClickListener is in listview Adapter

Comment: Where is your `ListView Adapter code` ?

Comment: in second Activity i.e MyAuctionHistoryAdapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34720781/2826147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `recycleRview` you can use getPosition to get the clickedItem Position
like below

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + getAdapterPosition());
            CustomBean bean =list.get(getAdapterPosition())
             String id = bean.getAcutionId()
              // now intent it
         }
```

By this position you will data from `ArrayList`

Comment: is it useful for you ?

Comment: Better to use `getAdapterPosition()` becoz `getPosition()` has been `deprecated`

Comment: Nop each row have different-2 auction_id and that id use as input for second activity

Comment: i think you have index(Position) of arraylist  item simply get data from that position and pass it to other activity

Comment: hey Anjali can I use this putExtra() and getExtra()

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi please explain i m getting null pointer exception

Comment: use getStringExtra("KEY")

Comment: refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097510/unable-to-get-intent-value/35098290?noredirect=1#comment57949186_35098290

Answer (score 0):

First of, given the name of the variable you declared "hRecyclerView", it seems that you are using a RecyclerView and not a Listview. I will assume that you are using a RecyclerView.

In your MyAuctionHistoryAdapter , you need to need to override the methods getItemId() and onBindViewHolder()

```
public class MyAuctionHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GenericRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder< MyAuctionListBean >> {

private List<MyAunctionListBean> mList = new ArrayList<Bean>();

public MyAunctionHistoryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList< MyAuctionListBean> list) {

mList = list;

//each item in the list will have the auction id as their id.
public int getItemId(position) {
  return mList.get(position).getAuncion_id();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{


    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA,getItemId(position));
      startActivity(intent);
     }

     });
}
```

Now everytime you click on an item in the list, it will go the other activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
public static final String EXTRA = "EXTRA";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// here is the intent you need
int aunctionId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA);



}

}
```