# Pass ArrayList between Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the rather specific `final List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();` (PieEntry is of MPAndroidChart) and I want to pass it to another fragment where it is then diplayed in a chart.
I have tried a number of ways like `parsing` it, but everytime I run the application the piechart seems to have no data to fill itself. (Maybe I didn't do it correctly because the explanation wasn't in depth enough for me).

I backwards tested it, so everything up until the array is fine, for example I can draw the chart in the first fragment and everything works.

Maybe I left some details out, or maybe I am going in the completely wrong direction?

Comment: did you try anything if yes post code snippet here

Comment: You could keep the list static or put it inot a bundle and setArgument for another Fragment.

Comment: Create a Bundle object and call putExtra method

Comment: > Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646430/pass-arraylist-from-one-fragment-to-another) it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arraylist with fragment 
follow below code

```
 List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
 entrie.add(additems);
 Fragment_FindABarDetail fragment;
 fragment = new Fragment_FindABarDetail().newInstance(entries);   
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment).commit();
```

in fragment add

```
static List<PieEntry> entries_infragment;
public Fragment_FindABarDetail fragment newInstance(List<PieEntry> entries){

entries_infragment=entries;

return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send parameters:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("user_name", myusername);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Receive parameters:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if (args  != null && args.containsKey("user_name"))
String userName = args.getString("user_name");
```

You can also try using static methods for passing data between fragments.