# empty Bundle when sending parcelable arraylist in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, parcelable

i'm working on android project, i want to send an arraylist of object that contain latitude and longitude from a fragment to another fragment to show multiple marker on the map but i get an empty argument.

**First Fragment**

```
private ArrayList<locationList> beirutList = new ArrayList<locationList>();
            beirutList.add(new locationList(34.077867,33.76087));
            Fragment mapapp = new MapApp();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putParcelableArrayList("list", beirutList);
            mapapp.setArguments(data);

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mapapp, "MappFrag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Second Fragment**

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_app, container,
                false);

        data = null;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            data = getArguments();
            Log.e("MapApp", "data is " + data.toString());

            if (data.getParcelableArrayList("list") != null) {
                beirutList = data.getParcelableArrayList("list");

            } else
                Toast.makeText(rootview.getContext(), "location is empty ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(rootview.getContext());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(rootview.getContext(), this, this);
        mLocationClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(this);
        mLocationClient.connect();

        return rootview;
    }
```

when i debug it the list in the Bundle (data variable) has the size 0

**locationList class**

```
 public class locationList implements Parcelable {
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<locationList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<locationList>() {
        @Override
        public locationList createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new locationList(source);
        }

        @Override
        public locationList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new locationList[size];
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeDouble(latitude);
        dest.writeDouble(longitude);

    }

    private locationList (Parcel bei){
        this.latitude = bei.readDouble();
        this.longitude = bei.readDouble();

    }

    public locationList(){

    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public locationList(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: is locationList parcelable ?

Comment: Yeah locationlist is parcelable i put the locationList class

Answer (score 1):

guess your creation from your `Parcel` is wrong.

Look at this implementation: [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable)

replace:

```
private locationList (Parcel bei){
    this.latitude = bei.readDouble();
    this.longitude = bei.readDouble();
}
```

with sth like:

```
public Student(Parcel in){
       String[] data = new String[3];

       in.readStringArray(data);
       this.id = data[0];
       this.name = data[1];
       this.grade = data[2];
   }
```

Comment: i did bundle.setString("asd") and setArgument(bundle); and try to get it from the other fragment but also the bundle is empty

Comment: @AliNrd first try to locate your error: pass simple String or int and see if they are passed to getArguments(), if its ok pass simple locationList object,  if its ok go back here with the bad news...

Comment: i passed simpled string but i got nothing in the other fragment

Comment: So your problem is not your Parcelable but the way you pass the arguments to the fragment...

Comment: exactly bro that what im talking about

Comment: and i try to get the argument from the onActivityCreated, onCreateView and the same problem exist

Answer (score -2):

Your `ArrayList`has to implement `Parcelable` too.

Please see the following solution. It's pretty similar to your approach --> [Android ArrayList<MyObject> pass as parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953121/android-arraylistmyobject-pass-as-parcelable)

Comment: No,  this is not true

Comment: It is, because Ali Nrd doesn't want to pass a simple `String Array`. Read the API before you downvote answers!

Comment: Read the API before answerring, he is using `public void putParcelableArrayList (String key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)` it means that `value` is an ArrayList which **contains** `Parcelable` elements, ArrayList itself doesn't need to be `Parcelable`