# Assigning constructor argument to member variable, ".this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, android

I have a class, `DFragment`. I'm passing a `List<Map<String, String>>` to its constructor, and I need to store the passed-in value in the member variable `subVitalList`.

I tried doing this:

```
this.subVitalList = subVitalList;
```

But I receive the following error on that line:

```
com.example.DFragment.this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I'm not sure how to do this. Here is the code for `DFragment`:

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Context context;
    List<Map<String, String>> subVitalList;
    ListView vitalEntryListView;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public static DFragment newInstance(List<Map<String, String>> subVitalList,int i) {
        DFragment f = new DFragment();
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt("num", num);
        args.putInt("num",i);

        //List<List<String>> svl = getArguments().getStringArrayList(subVitalList);
        return f;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly store the passed-in value in my member variable?

Comment: can you expound on "but its not working"...?

Comment: it says com.example.DFragment.this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: you must pass `subVitalList` to argument and get that in `onCreateView` or other fragment's method. you can't set like `this.subVitalList = subVitalList;` because `newInstance` is `static` method, you can't set non static value to static value.

Comment: Sorry, not clear. how do I get it in onCreateView?

Comment: you must create class and implement `Parcelable` or `serializable` and use getArgument().get.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953121/android-arraylistmyobject-pass-as-parcelable

Comment: `static DFragment newInstance(...)` is a _factory method_, not a _constructor_!

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a class to implement Parcelable. I'm only using list.add(map) to add elements to the list.

Comment: is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Cant you just do `f.subVitalList = subVitalList` ? (you also may need to make a deep copy of the list instead of just holding the reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this ,

Fragment class ,

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment {

    List<Map<String, String>> mylist;

    public DFragment () {   
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    public DFragment (List<Map<String, String>> mylist) {
        this.mylist= mylist;
    }

}
```

You can pass the list as follows:

```
DFragment dialog = new DFragment (mylist);
```