# How can I wire together this Custom ListView ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, mpandroidchart

This question isn't specific to the MPAndroidChart lib, but I'm expanding on the MPAndroidChart example app's `ListViewMultiChartActivity` [`ChartDataAdapter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/ListViewMultiChartActivity.java#L66), and it abstracts out the RowItems ([`ChartItem`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/listviewitems/ChartItem.java)s in this case). Now, I'm used to holding all of my logic in the ArrayAdapter's `getView()`, but in this case, it seems to be abstracted out [into their own classes](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/listviewitems/LineChartItem.java). My problem is being able to update the `ChartItem` from within the different [`ChartItem`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/listviewitems)s..

Should I be passing through a copy of the `ArrayAdapter`, or the `ArrayList<ChartItem>`, into my different `ChartItem` `getViews()`? I have no issue holding and passing the reference/position in my chart's tag, but I still don't know how to update that single row in the list and update the adapter FROM the ChartItem itself.

I've tried different methods.. I've tried abstracting out `getItem()` into each `ChartItem`, but I don't think I understand Java abstraction enough to get what's going on here. I've tried referencing the `ChartItem` as `this` in each `ChartItem`, and while I can update the row, it updates every other row of the same `ChartItem` type..

I'm sure it's something simple I'm not wrapping my head around.. I think it has to do with the abstraction and not fully understanding what's happening there.  I'd rather not move all of my ChartItem getView logic into my ArrayAdapter. I can't seem to find one other example where the RowItems/ChartItems are abstracted out like this.. at least not with updates to the list. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've been messing with the `ChartData<cd>` that's being passed into my `LineChartItem`, and I can successfully modify datasets and have the change persists against re-draws of the list.. and then I'm calling `chart.invalidate()` and `cd.notifyDataSetChanged()`.. but my changes don't persist on rotation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to save the `ChartItem`s `ChartData<?>` for anyone else in the same boat.. I made my `ChartItem` implement `Parcleable` and then flattened the ChartData array into a Json string based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14047322/350237).  Works like a charm..