# Deserialise a generic list in Gson

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, gson

I want to write a generic function which deserialise a generic type List with Gson
here is the code:

```
private <T> List<T> GetListFromFile(String filename)
    {
        //Read textfile
        BufferedReader reader;
        String data="";
        try 
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            data = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
        {

        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {

        }
        if (data == null) 
        {
            List<T> Spiel = new ArrayList<T>();
            return Spiel;
        }
        else
        {
            //get list with Deserialise
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<T> something = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType());
            return something;
        }
    }
```

But this code is not working, i get a strange structure but not a List of my type

When i'am using:

```
List<concreteType> something = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType());
```

i works i get a `List<concreteType>`!!

But i need a generic function, how can i fix it?

Regards
rubiktubik

Comment: You can't, due to type erasure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do it without passing actual type of `T` (as `Class<T>`) to your method.

But if you pass it explicitly, you can create a `TypeToken` for `List<T>` as follows:

```
private <T> List<T> GetListFromFile(String filename, Class<T> elementType) {
    ...
    TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {};
    List<T> something = gson.fromJson(data, token.getType());
    ...
}
```

**See also:**

- [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html)

Comment: How come you have passed `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken` to  `com.google.gson.fromJson()` ?

Comment: @tfranckiewicz `TypeToken<Type>() {}.getType()` is a convenience idiom to construct a `Type` object which represents a complete generic type. In this case, `List<T>`, for an arbitrary, specific `T`. Passing `List.class` to `fromJson` does not work, because it doesn't capture the type of the list's elements. [Documentation here.](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-generic-types)

Comment: This doesn't work. `T` is erased, so `gson` does not actually receive the type information. It will just use a default type as element type for `ArrayList` to parse.

Answer (score 10):

**The approach of use TypeToken won't work.**

```
new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>()
```

is not possible because of how generics (type erasure) and reflection works. The whole `TypeToken` hack works because `Class#getGenericSuperclass()` does the following

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
>   (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the Type object returned
>   must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source
>   code.

In other words, if it sees `ArrayList<T>`, that's the `ParameterizedType` it will return and you won't be able to extract the compile time value that the type variable `T` would have had.

`Type` and `ParameterizedType` are both interfaces. You can provide an instance of your own implementation.

So, you have two options:

**Option 1:**
implement `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` yourself and pass it to Gson.

```
private static class ListParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {

    private Type type;

    public ListParameterizedType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {type};
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

    // implement equals method too! (as per javadoc)
}
```

Then simply:

```
Type type = new ListParameterizedType(clazz);
List<T> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Note that as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), equals method should also be implemented.

**Option 2:** Parse the list manually and then for each element use Gson

```
public <T> List<T> listEntity(Class<T> clazz)
        throws WsIntegracaoException {
    try {
        // Consuming remote method
        String strJson = getService().listEntity(clazz.getName());

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(strJson).getAsJsonArray();

        List<T> lst =  new ArrayList<T>();
        for(final JsonElement json: array){
            T entity = GSON.fromJson(json, clazz);
            lst.add(entity);
        }

        return lst;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WsIntegracaoException(
                "WS method error [listEntity()]", e);
    }
}
```