# How to deserialize different subtypes with generics with one gson deserializer

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, gson, type-erasure

I have to save configuration objects for different testcases. I decided to use GSON for that, since i have worked with that already. The problem is the structure/inheritance of the configuration file contains generics in its definition. If this is a duplicate, i have read the thread, but couldn't apply it to my problem. The code is broken down to the minimum.

### The configuration class

Besides other easy to serialize components it has an `ArrayList<T>`.

```
//There are classes that inherit from that too
public class Configuration<T extends ParamSet> implements Iterable<T>{

    // this list is what i want to set from my ApplicationClass
    private ArrayList<T> _paramSets = new ArrayList<T>();

    //getter, setter and constructor
}
```

### The ParameterSet definitions

There is nothing special in these classes. Just Integer and Boolean values.

```
public class ParamSet {}

public class ChildParamSet extends ParamSet{}
```

### Abstract Application class

This is where the saving process starts. I have defined a abstract method later implemented in classes where `T` is known at runtime.

```
public abstract class ApplicationClass<T extends ParamSet>{

    private Configuration<T> config;

    // in this method i want to set either a new config or new params in the config
    public setupConfig(){
        //some checks and if the user wants to load a config from file
        loadConfig(file);       
    }
    //abstract method to be called in more concrete classes
    abstract protected Configuration<T> loadConfig(File file);
}
```

### Concrete Application class

Well here i know the type of `T` and i want to call a `getConfiguration`method.

```
public abstract class MoreConcreteApplicationClass extends ApplicationClass<ChildParamSet>{

    //constructor and other stuff

    @Override
    protected Configuration<ChildParamSet> loadConfig(File file){
        return ConfigurationPersistenceHelper.getConfiguration(file);
    }   
}
```

### Configuration Persistence Helper -- the problem

```
public class ConfigurationPersistenceHelper(){

    //i get the configuration with a linked treeMap --> wrong type 
    public static <T extends ParamSet> Configuration<T> getConfiguration(final File location){
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        GsonBuilder builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization.create();

        final Type type = new TypeToken<Configuration<T>>(){}.getType();

        final String jsonRepresentation =  new String(Files.readAllBytes(location.toPath()));
        return gson.fromJson(jsonRepresentation, type);

    }
}
```

So the problem is the `getConfiguration` method in the ConfigurationPersistenceHelper. When i run this method, instead of an `ArrayList<ChildParamSet>` i get a `Linked TreeMap` in the configuration.

I guess this is because of type erasure for generics during runtime and my definition of the method with `T extends ParamSet`.

*But how can i fix this? Is there another way to call the method so the type isn´t lost?*

#### Workarounds i know of

I know i can implement the deserializer logic in the `loadConfig` method of every concrete application class. But this would have a lot of duplicate code as a result. This is my current solution.

Also i know i can pass the type to the serializer from the `loadConfig` (where the type is still available at runtime) to the `getConfiguration` method. Is that bad practice?

I also know i can write my own deserializer but there i would also need the type at runtime, which is currently my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Type Erasure is the problem. Just pass in the type info like so:

```
abstract protected Configuration<T> loadConfig(File file, Class<T> clazz);
```

inside that method use a custom ParameterizedType for your ArrayList, see:

- [Java Type Generic as Argument for GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson)
- [Deserialise a generic list in Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320562/deserialise-a-generic-list-in-gson)

Comment: I always thought it might be bad practice if you pass the class type when using generics, but it seems this is pretty common.

Comment: yep it is pretty common to do this (e.g. https://github.com/google/guava/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=clazz)