# Gson Parsing Generic List From Reflected Field Type

Tags: java, list, generics, serialization, gson

I am having an issue translating List types from a reflected object into the set method of that object.

I am not sure if the issue is on the front end or on the Gson parsing end, but my test code is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String json = "[52881]";
    ListObject lo = new ListObject();
    for(Field f : lo.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        if(List.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())){
            Method m = lo.getClass().getMethod(
                    new StringBuilder("set").append(f.getName().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()).append(f.getName().substring(1,f.getName().length())).toString(),
                    f.getType()
            );
            System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) f.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            getListFromJson(m, lo, json, 
                    ((ParameterizedType) f.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass());
        }
    ListObject p = (ListObject) lo;
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(p.getAList()));
    for(long pid : p.getAList()){
        System.out.println(pid);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> void getListFromJson(Method m, Object target, String json, Class<T> elementType) throws Exception {
        m.invoke(target, (List<T>)gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType()));
}
```

And the ListObject:

```
public class ListObject {

    List<Long> aList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public List<Long> getAList() {
        return aList;
    }

    public void setAList(List<Long> aList) {
        this.aList = aList;
    }
}
```

This test program yields the following output:

> class java.lang.Long
>
> [52881.0]
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>       at test.GenericTester.main(GenericTester.java:66)

Where line 66 is the

```
for(long pid : p.getAList()){
```

I am making use of this answer here for the getList method:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321048/2555197

Comment: As error message states, you cannot convert `52881.0` Double into Long. Check your input data

Comment: Look at the second answer of the question you linked, it is correct, the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: I'll look into the 2nd answer also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of how Java generics are implemented: `<T>` can only exist in compiler's mind or in class file metadata. Let's take a closer look and perform a brief analysis:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> void getListFromJson(Method m, Object target, String json, Class<T> elementType) throws Exception {
        m.invoke(target, (List<T>)gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType()));
}
```

- `Class<T> elementType` does not play here at all because of that Java generics restrictions. It's just an attempt to put some generic restrictions for the method, but if you'd remove the parameter, *nothing* would ever change. Moreover, `Class<T>` can hold raw types only, and even if you use unchecked casts to make `Class<T>` hold something like `List<List<List<String>>>`, you'll still get the top-most raw type `List`, and you could remove the parameter (however, hold it for a scenario described below).
- Type tokens are based on the fact that JVM allows to store the super class parameterization. You might notice that type tokens are parameterized with type parameters known at compile time: `new TypeToken<String>` or `new TypeToken<List<Integer>>` -- in this case compiler can generate proper superlcass parameterization based on *known* types. These types are used in type tokens. `<T>` is *unknown* at compile time. Check it in runtime: `System.out.println(new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType());` -- the output is `T`. What is `T`? Just a wildcard, not a real type.
- You have to understand what type tokens are for: they are just a convenient way of what could Java support if there were something like `List<Integer>.type` (illegal and not `.class`!). Type tokens just analyze their parameterizations are return `Type` instances that *may* be `ParameterizedType` instances. Moreover, you *can* create your own `ParameterizedType` without type tokens, because these are just interfaces that define some getters. So, in order to build type tokens dynamically:

  - if you're using Gson 2.8.0, use `TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, elementType).getType()`;
  - if you have an older Gson version or you want control it as much as possible, just create and return a `ParameterizedType` instance yourself:

```java
new ParameterizedType() {
    @Override public Type getRawType() { return List.class; }
    @Override public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() { return new Type[]{ elementType }; }
    @Override public Type getOwnerType() { return null; }
}
```

Pretty self-descriptive, isn't it?

- Why does Gson returns `Double`s rather than `Long`s? Having a wildcard of `<T>`, Gson uses the default strategy as if the type was completely unknown: doubles are used by default for all numbers since they can keep all standard Java number values. And that's why you get the cast exception when you're dereferencing a list element only (but not lists -- type parameters do not exist for local variables.)

Sorry for such a vague explanation, but summarizing it all up, you only need the following method:

```
static <T> void getListFromJson(final Method method, final Object target, final String json, final Type elementType)
        throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    final List<T> ts = gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, elementType).getType());
    method.invoke(target, ts);
}
```

Note that now the `elementType` parameter plays the game, the type tokens are used to create a `ParameterizedType` instance, and Gson now can use deserializations strategy for the type defined with `elementType` (`Long` in that place).

Output:

> class java.lang.Long
>   [52881]
>   52881

Comment: Marvelous!  Thank you, I knew I was missing some small but significant detail.  This advances my understanding of generic types also.