# How can i serialize/deserialize with gson, with generic method

Tags: java, json, gson

i got a problem, and i just can't resolve it.

Well, i got this code for deserialize list, but in this list i got my object "Team"

```
Object team
    public Team(String name, String itemName, ChatColor color, String worldName, int spawnX,
                int spawnY, int spawnZ, Material material,
                List<UUID> playerList, OneBlock oneBlock, int maxPlayerAllowed, int buildX, int buildY, int buildZ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.color = color;
        this.spawnWorld = worldName;
        this.spawnX = spawnX;
        this.spawnY = spawnY;
        this.spawnZ = spawnZ;
        this.material = material;
        this.playerList = playerList;
        this.oneBlock = oneBlock;
        this.maxPlayerAllowed = maxPlayerAllowed;
        this.buildX = buildX;
        this.buildY = buildY;
        this.buildZ = buildZ;
    }
```

```
Deserialize method
    public <T> List<T> deserializeList(String json, Class<T> type) {


        TypeToken<Collection<Class<T>>> collectionType = new TypeToken<>() {
        };

        return this.gson.fromJson(json, collectionType.getType());
    }
```

And i got this error when i'm trying to deserialize:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class fr.wailroth.buildbattle.team.Team (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; fr.wailroth.buil
dbattle.team.Team is in unnamed module of loader org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader @773c2bb4)
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Can you please provide the JSON?

Comment: `Class<T>` cannot work -- it *can't* retain class parameterization, thus `Class<List<Integer>>` *equals* `Class<List<String>>`. Next, `<T>` in your example, is only a type variable, therefore Gson *can't* know the real `T` unless you pass it from outside. What you're looking for is merely `public static <T> T deserialize(final Gson gson, final JsonReader jsonReader, final TypeToken<? extends T> typeToken) { return gson.fromJson(jsonReader, typeToken.getType()); }`, or use any `ParameterizedType` implementation instead of type tokens.

Comment: See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269029/gson-parsing-generic-list-from-reflected-field-type