# Can I override Gson's built-in number converters directly (not by delegation)?

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am using Gson to convert my JSON data to a `Map<String, Object>`. My JSON has some integer (actually long) fields, and I want them to be parsed as long (obviously). However, Gson parses them as doubles. How can I make Gson parse them as longs/integers? I've seen [How to deserialize a list using GSON or another JSON library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318458/how-to-deserialize-a-list-using-gson-or-another-json-library-in-java) but I don't want to create a strongly-typed custom class, I'll be using a Map. I've also seen [Android: Gson deserializes Integer as Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321553/android-gson-deserializes-integer-as-double) and a few other questions which I've thought might be duplicates, but all the answers either point to creating a strongly-typed class, creating extra functions that play role in deserialization or using completely another library.

Isn't there a simple way in Google's own JSON serializer/deserializer that will simply deserialize an integer (yeah, a number *without* a dot at all) as an integer and not double, as it should have been as default in the first place? If I wanted to send a floating point, I'd be sending `2.0`, not `2` from my server JSON. Why on Earth am I getting a double and how do I get rid of it?

**UPDATE:** Even though I've clearly explained, some people still don't understand the simple fact that I am **not** in for another library (e.g. Jackson) and I'm aware of the simple fact that any parser should be able to identify `2.0` as a floating-point and `2` as a pure integer and parse accordingly, so please stop pointing me to telling **why** it's that way because it's simply incorrect and is not an excuse not to parse integers correctly. So, no, this is **not** a duplicate of [Gson. Deserialize integers as integers and not as doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090589/gson-deserialize-integers-as-integers-and-not-as-doubles).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson. Deserialize integers as integers and not as doubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090589/gson-deserialize-integers-as-integers-and-not-as-doubles) this question have an answer on **why** and an **alternative** to use Jackson

Comment: FWIW, Square's Moshi seems to default to the same behavior as Gson: When asked for a `JsonAdapter<Map<String, Object>> adapter = moshi.adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class))` that adapter will then parse "1000" as the Double `1000.0`.

Comment: @Yazan and I've **clearly** stated that  I don't want to use another library and use Gson and any decent enough library should be able to differentiate between `2.0` and `2` as a float and int so that answer on **why** is irrelevant. I've read that question and this is *not* a duplicate. if there is no way of doing this using Gson itself, then the answer would be `no`.

Comment: well, last thing i recall your title was `Why does Gson deserialize my JSON's integer fields as Double` **WHY** the question i posted is clearly states WHY, not irrelevant, JSON HAVE NO INTEGER TYPE ONLY DOUBLE if you can't understand or accept that, it's your problem

Comment: @Yazan it's not me who changed the title, someone else edited it. i do understand what it means at least as much as you do, don't worry. it still isn't relevant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

### Long answer

You can't override gson's built-in numbers converters.

I've made a short code test to peek under the hood which types gson tries to find a delegated converter.

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class SO36528727 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    @Language("JSON")
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"anInteger\": 2,\n" +
            "  \"aDouble\": 2.0\n" +
            "}";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new LongDeserializerFactory())
            .create();
    Map<String, Object> m =
            gson.fromJson(json,
                          new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());

    System.out.println(m.get("aDouble").getClass());
    System.out.println(m.get("anInteger").getClass());
  }

  private static class LongDeserializerFactory
          implements TypeAdapterFactory
  {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
      System.out.println("type = " + type);

      if (type.getRawType().equals(String.class)) {
        TypeAdapter<String> stringAdapter =
                gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(String.class));
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
          @Override
          public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
            stringAdapter.write(out, (String) value);
          }

          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          @Override
          public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            String s = stringAdapter.read(in);
            System.out.println("s = " + s);
            return (T) s;
          }
        };
      } else
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The execution result is this:

```
type = java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
type = java.lang.String
s = anInteger
s = aDouble
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
```

So, you can see that gson looks just for two converters: the whole `Map<>` thing and the basic `String`. But no `Double` or `Integer` or `Number` or even `Object`. So you CAN'T override it unless you override it from a higher place like when dealing with a `Map`. And that [was answered on the thread you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27898782/518992) on the question.

Comment: thanks, i think i'll try this and if I need more converters, just use the same pattern, or if I mess up, I think I'll go with another library as the final option.