# How to read JSON file in Java with simple json?

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, int

If I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "Johnny",
  "Gender": {
    "male": true,
    "female": false
  },
  "What does Johnny likes?": ["Travels", "Woman"],
  "Travels": [
    {
      "Country": "Spain",
      "City": "Madrid"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Greece",
      "City": "Kalokairi"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that I can do this to access to **name**:

```
object.getString("name");
```

To access **gender** I can do this:

```
JSONObject gender = (JSONObject) object.get("Gender");
gender.get("male");
gender.get("female");
```

To access **What does Johnny likes?** I can:

```
JSONArray likes = (JSONArray) objet.get("What does Johnny likes?");
        Iterator<String> iterator = likes.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            //code here
        }
```

But how do I access **Travels**? I'm really not sure to understand it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize a list using GSON or another JSON library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318458/how-to-deserialize-a-list-using-gson-or-another-json-library-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

did you, try this?

```
JSONArray travels = (JSONArray) objet.get("Travels");
for(int j=0;j<travels.length();j++){
    JSONObject travel = travels.getJSONObject(j);
}
```